# How can I contact Bitcoin.org

Tags: security

I need to contact with some support from "bitcoin.org". Ive tried to found some email adress or contact with them with their web, but its simply impossible. Somebody know how can i contact them?

Thx.

Comment: Create an issue in this repository and tag [Cobra](https://github.com/Cobra-Bitcoin): https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/Bitcoin.org/issues

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

https://bitcoincore.org/en/contact/

or twitter?

Twitter: @bitcoincoreorg

Greetings

Comment: Question is regarding bitcoin.org, not bitcoincore.org